# Pulling env variables from JSON file and passing the variable to terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm new to terraform and I'm trying to use Terraform to deploy a lambda functions in AWS and pass the environment variables from a JSON file to terraform.  I can't set these values in the main.tf or in a tfvars file as those env variables would be different for every lambda that is deployed.

I've tried pulling the values from the JSON using jq and putting them in a file and then having those passed thru to the variable but when I run the terraform init command I get an error.

Below is how the values look in the JSON file.

```
"environment": {
    "value1": "aa",
    "value2": "aa",
    "value3": "aa",
    "value4": "aa",
    "value5": "aa",
    "value6": "aa"
  },
```

In my main.tf I have the environment section set as such so the values can be passed thru.  I set the envVars variables in a variable.tf file and then pass that when I run the terraform init and terraform apply commands.

```
environment {
   variables {
       "${var.envVars}"
      }
    }
```

What I would like to have happen is that the values above would be set in the terraform file in the needed format so terraform can read it.

```
environment {
   variables {
     value1 = "",
     value2 = "",
     value3 = "",
     value4 = "",
     value5 = "",
     value6 = ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thinking to use type of `map` to manage these values.

```
variable "envVars" {}
variable "environment" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    dev = "<value_1>"
    uat = "<value_2>"
    prod = "<value_3>"
  }
}
```

So in your tf codes, you can easily reference as  `"${var.environment[var.envVars]}"`